# How to split heatmap tick labels between categories?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have DataFrame with there columns ['Employee Name', 'Skill Name', 'Category', 'Year', 'Score']. I want to display these data on heatmap. 
X axis: Employee Name
Y axis: Skill Name
Value: Score

Moreover I want to split skill between categories so Y axis labels will be presented as below

```
Category 1
skill 1
skill 2
skill 3

Category 2
skill 4
skill 5
skill 6

Category 3
skill 7
skill 8
[...]
```

I do not know if it is possible to put additional line to heatmap for each category which will split chart with white line. Any ideas?